# How to prevent malicious developers from interferring with firebase in android

Tags: android, database, security, firebase, rule

I want to make an app which updates my firebase database but I see that no "secret" key etc is required and a developer only needs to know the firebase url to interfere with it. I don't think it will be hard to know the url when I am making changes from the client side. The security rules, as I slightly read them, can only prevent them so far.

Basically the idea is that the users will do something and the code will decide to increment a value by 10. I can make this a security rule, but the problem will occur when a malicious developer will use his own code to increment it again and again when the value should not be incremented. What can I do to make sure that only my app can update the value?
Can I pass a key or something as a parameter when updating database which the "trespasser" will not know?

Comment: Basically you can't :/ If you pass a key then that key will have to be published in the app (which is public)

Comment: What if I hard code some login credentials etc. and use them as security? I am not educated about networks..

Comment: Take this in mind when putting hardcoded credentials in an app: ALL code is prone to reverse engineering in android. Don't put credentials in it.

Comment: You could check out [firebase security](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/) for basic understanding of security mechanisms supplied by Firebase.

Comment: Sounds like a good answer @PedroOliveira. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Allow read/writes only when user is authenticated, you can allow anonymous login. Your google-services json will have API key, you need to restrict usage of that key to your package-id and client SHA1 through Cloud [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials).